# Javascript Not working on form submit

Tags: javascript, php

I have wrote javascript in php file the thing is that i want to select input from dropdown using javascript the default value in dropdown is SELECT and when i submit the form i need the alert message like please select value in drop down lable. and apart from this i also need this for all dropdown option.wherever it found "SELECT" alert should be there with respective lable

My try is:

```
<?php   
    include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/riteshproject/config.php");         ?>

<?php       if(isset($_POST['empsubmit']))    {         
if(isset($_POST['areaname']) && isset($_POST['flat']) &&
isset($_POST['rentsale']))       {

            $an=$_POST['areaname'];             $flat=$_POST['flat'];
            $rentsale=$_POST['rentsale'];

                        $_SESSION['an']=$an;            $_SESSION['flat']=$flat;            $_SESSION['rentsale']=$rentsale;         }
            }   if(isset($_REQUEST['unsetsession']))    {       session_destroy();;
                header('location:home.php');        break;  } ?>


<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>   <title>Shree Shree
Property,Kolhapur</title>   <meta charset="utf-8">   <meta
name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {height: 450px}

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 1em 15px;      margin-top: 50px;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .row.content {height:auto;}     .active { background-color: #00bfff; } 
    }   .col-sm-2{background-color:   gray;}    .col-sm-8{background-color: #e0e0eb; border-radius: 25px;}
    .mainBlock4{background-color: gray; overflow: scroll;   height:
220px;}     .mainBlock5{background-color: gray; overflow: scroll;  
height: 240px;}         th{text-align: center; background-color:black;
color:white;}    .td1{color:black;}
       .tr1:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #e0e0eb;  }   .trclose{}      .closebutton{ border-collapse: collapse;}       .button {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.1px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 2px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;    border: 2px solid red;}         .button:hover {
    background-color: gray; /* Green */
    color: white;

       </style> </head> <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <img src="../riteshproject/logo.png" align="center" style="width:70px;height:50px;">
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li><a href="../riteshproject/home.php" class="active">Home</a></li>        <li class="current" id="dddd"><a
href="../riteshproject/aboutus.php" >About US</a></li>      <li><a
href="#">Contact US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Add Property</a></li>       <li><a href="#">Luxarious Property</a></li>         <li><a href="#">Property For
Sale</a></li>       <li><a href="#">Other Services</a></li>
             </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../riteshproject/Login/login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span><img
src="../riteshproject/login1.jpg" width="60" height="25"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>   </div> </nav>    <div class="container-fluid text-center">       <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav" align="center" id="2">
            <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var picPaths = ['../riteshproject/img/prop1.jpg','../riteshproject/img/prop2.jpg','../riteshproject/img/prop3.jpg','../riteshproject/img/prop4.jpg',
                           '../riteshproject/img/prop5.jpg'];
            var curPic = -1;
            //preload the images for smooth animation
            var imgO = new Array();
            for(i=0; i < picPaths.length; i++) {
                imgO[i] = new Image();
                imgO[i].src = picPaths[i];
            }

            function swapImage() {
                curPic = (++curPic > picPaths.length-1)? 0 : curPic;
                imgCont.src = imgO[curPic].src;
                setTimeout(swapImage,2000);
            }

            window.onload=function() {
                imgCont = document.getElementById('imgBanner');
                swapImage();
            }
        </script>

     </head>
     <body>
          <div>
            <img id="imgBanner" src="" alt="" />
          </div>
     </body> 
         <div>

      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left">      <form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="notSELECT()">
      <table><tr><td><h4><b>Welcome To Shree Shree Property,Kolhapur</b></h4></td></tr></table>
      <hr>
        <h5><b><i><marquee width="365px" height="10px" direction=slide BEHAVIOR=ALTERNATE left:355px>Search Property in
kolhapur... </marquee></i></b></h5>
      </hr>
      <table>     <tr>    </tr>       <tr>    </tr>       <tr>    <td width='35px'></td>      <td>
      <select name="rentsale"  id="rentsale" value="select">
                                    <option>RENT</option>
                                    <option>SALE</option>
                                                 </select>
     </td>
         <td><input type="radio" name="radio" value="flat" checked>FLAT</td>
     <td width='35px'></td>      <td><input type="radio" name="radio" value="Bungalo">Bungalow</td>      </tr>   <tr height="60px">

                        <td height="20px" />Area
                        <td style="text-align:left">

                                    <select name="areaname"  id="areaname" value="select" class="NotEmpty">
                                    <option value="SELECT" style="display:none">SELECT</option>
                                        <?php 

                                            $query="select code,areaname from areamaster";
                                            $query_run=mysql_query($query);
                                            mysql_num_rows($query_run);

                                            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))

                                            {
                                            ?>

                                            <option value="<?php echo $row['areaname']?>"><?php echo $row['areaname']?></option>
                                            <?php
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                            </td>
                           <td></td>
                            <td>Flat</td>
                            <td style="text-align:left">

                                    <select name="flat"  id="flat" value="select">
                                    <option value="SELECT" style="display:none">SELECT</option>
                                        <?php 

                                             $query="select flat from flatmaster";
                                            $query_run=mysql_query($query);
                                            mysql_num_rows($query_run);

                                            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))

                                            {
                                            ?>

                                            <option value="<?php echo $row['flat']?>"><?php echo $row['flat']?></option>
                                            <?php
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                            </td>
     </tr>   <tr>
       <td>
       </td>
       <td>
       </td>
       <td>
            <input type="submit" name="empsubmit" style="width:75" id="submit" value="Search" class="button" onclick="showDiv()">
       </td>     </tr>   </table>   </form> 
     <?php      if(isset($_SESSION['an']))      { 

        ?>
        <div class="heddendiv" width="30px">
         <html><b>
         Property Found for your search...</b>
                 <div  Class="mainBlock4" style="width:100%"> 
                             <form name="leavesanction" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="notSELECT()" >
                                <table border=3px solid black;> 
                                        <tr>
                                            <th width="15%" align="center">Area</th>
                                            <th width="15%" align="center">Flat/Bungalo</th>
                                            <th width="12%" align="center">BHK</th>
                                            <th width="12%">Rent</th>
                                            <th width="16%">Deposit</th>
                                            <th width="10%">SQ Ft</th>
                                            <th width="10%">FLoor</th>
                                            <th width="10%">Lift</th>
                                         </tr>

                                          <?php

                                              $select="select area,proptype,address,bhk,rent,diposit,sqft,floor,lift 
                                                       from propertymaster where area='$an' and bhk='$flat' and  rentorsale='$rentsale'";
                                              $property=mysql_query($select);
                                              while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($property))
                                              {
                                               ?>
                                               <tr class="tr1">
                                                <td class="td1">
                                                    <?php echo $row['area'];?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                    <?php echo $row['proptype'];?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo $row['bhk'];?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo $row['rent'];?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo $row['diposit'];?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo $row['sqft'];?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo $row['floor'];?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="20px">
                                                    <?php echo $row['lift'];?>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr> 
                                             <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        </table>
                                <table class="closebutton">
                                <tr class="trclose" align="center">
                                <td></td>
                                <td width='260px'></td>
                                <td>
                                <a href="home.php?unsetsession=1">
                                       <input type="submit" name="Close" style="width:75" id="Close" value="Close" class="button"></a>
                                  </td> 
                                </tr>       
                                </table>
                             </form>
       </div>                       
      </html>
     </div>
     <?php                              } ?>


 <?php  if(!isset($_SESSION['an']))     {    ?>
     <div Class="mainBlock5" style="width:100%">
       <p>testing div</p>    </div>
            <?php       }       ?> 

 </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>      <img src="../riteshproject/login1.jpg" width="80" height="50">
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>   </div> </div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">  
<p><b><marquee>Designed,Developed and Maintened By Shree Shree
Property,Kolhapur Mob No 9373002173</b></marquee></p> </footer>
</body> </html>

<script>  function notSELECT()   {
            var inputControls = document.getElementsByClassName("areaname");
            if (inputControls.value== "SELECT")         {
            alert("Enter Proper search Values");

            return false;
        } 

    return true;  }

</script>
```

in javascript i done following with function

i get the values using `getElementByName`
and using if condition i checked it with "SELECT"
and shown `alert();`
i wrote that function in form tag `onsubmit="notSELECT()"`

so plz help me out to show alert msg

please help me

Comment: Flagged as low quality. Please edit and better format your question because in it's current state, it is unlikely to get good answers

Comment: the main thing is that  i wrote javascript inside php function notSELECT() 
 {
   
 
 var inputControls = document.getElementsByClassName("areaname");
 
  if (inputControls.value== "SELECT") 
  {
            alert("Enter Proper search Values");
   
            return false;
        } 
      
    return true;
 }

</script> is it write ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
function notSELECT()   {
    var inputControls = document.getElementsByClassName("areaname");
    if (inputControls.value== "SELECT")         {
        alert("Enter Proper search Values");
        return false;
    }
    return true;  
}
```

You try to select all elements with the className of "areaname", but I can't seem to find any class with that name. Perhaps this is what you wanted:

```
function notSELECT()   {
    var inputControls = document.getElementById("areaname");
    if (inputControls.value== "SELECT")         {
        alert("Enter Proper search Values");
        return false;
    }
    return true;  
}
```

EDIT:
For your second question (you stated in the comments) here is the code:

```
function notSELECT()   {
    var inputControlsAreaName = document.getElementById("areaname");
    var inputControlsFlat = document.getElementById("flat");
    if (inputControlsAreaName.value== "SELECT")         {
        alert("Please select areaname");
        return false;
    }
    if (inputControlsFlat.value== "SELECT")         {
        alert("Please select flat");
        return false;
    }
    return true;  
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `getElementById` instead of `getElementsById`

Comment: ok i tried document.getElementsById() also still i am not getting alert

Comment: great answer @Andew its working .the only thing remaining is that i want to tell in alert that where user want to select value .that is for which label

Comment: @Andrew Whoops indeed! Forgot to delete the "s". Thanks for pointing out, edited my answer

Comment: that is please select Areaname   or please select flat

Comment: I can see that you have trouble with English, but as far as I can guess what you are trying to ask, I have no idea what you meant with your previous comment. Please elaborate?

Comment: there are two dropdown options which are having SELECT as a default values .i want alert as "Please Select Areaname " .if i selected areaname and not selecting flat then "Please Select flat"  Something like that          alert("Please select"+ inputControls);  but it gives me Please select[object HTMLSelectElement]

Comment: i tried alert("Please select"+inputControls.name); and its working but after click on ok the form get submited automaticaly

Comment: yes i tried your updated code i got alert msg which i want but form get submited. it should stop as it is

Comment: the thing is that i have used session .when i click on search button session get started and hidden div get shown  may be this is reason

Comment: If this answer was any helpful for you, please consider to upvote :) it helps other people to find answers for their questions

Comment: @RiteshFondke You should change your form element so it has `onsubmit="return notSELECT()"`

Comment: yes i got solution.it work exactly like as i want great work from you gays